# How do I implement a "Beeping" Sound to my code?

Tags: java, eclipse, interface, inner-classes

So my code runs fine and all; no problems, or atleast I think it doesn't have any; I need to add two final things: first one is a way to make a beep sound (think I have to use toolkit, actionListener, etc) and the other thing, is a way to print the current random number the program generates (something like a toString). I've tried my professor's methods for the beep sound and nothing, so now I'm here. Thanks in advance.

Tried some methods from my professors code but nothing.

```
//Interface
package edu.pupr.LottoGame;

public interface Ask {
    public void ask();
}

//Class
package edu.pupr.LottoGame;

import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class theLotto {
    //VARIABLE
    public int values;
    //OVERLOAD CONSTRUCTOR
    public theLotto(int values) {
        this.values = values;
    }
    //MUTATOR
    public void setValues(int values) {
        this.values = values;
    }
    //ACCESSOR
    public int getValues() {
        return values;
    }
    //ANONYMOUS CLASS
    public void start() {
        Ask ak = new Ask() {
            public void ask() {
                //ANONYMOUS VARIABLES USED
                String input = null;
                int reply;
                int randomNum;
                //BEGINNING OF FIRST DO-WHILE
                do {
                    //INPUT OF USER : 4 DIGITS
                    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Plese enter 4 digits (1000-9999)");
                    values = Integer.parseInt(input);
                }while(values < 1000 || values > 9999);
                //ENDING OF FIRST DO WHILE

                //RANDOM NUMBER GENERATOR
                Random rn = new Random();
                randomNum =  1000 + rn.nextInt(10000 - 1000);
                //DETERMINES IF THE USER WON OR LOST
                if(values == randomNum)
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You Won! The num: " + randomNum);
                else
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You Lost! The wining num was: " + randomNum);
                //BEGINNING OF SECOND DO-WHILE
                do {
                    //WANNA PLAY AGAIN PANEL
                    reply = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Continue?", null, JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                    //IF OPTION IS YES
                    if (reply == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                        //BEGINNIG OF THIRD DO-WHILE
                        do {
                            //INPUT OF USER : 4 DIGITS
                            input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Plese enter 4 digits (1000-9999)");
                            values = Integer.parseInt(input);
                        }while(values < 1000 || values > 9999);
                        //END OF THIRD DO-WHILE

                        //RANDOM NUMBER GENERATOR
                        Random rn2 = new Random();
                        randomNum =  1000 + rn2.nextInt(10000 - 1000);
                        //DETERMINES IF THE USER WON OR LOST
                        if(values == randomNum)
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You Won! The num: " + randomNum);
                        else
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You Lost! The wining num was: " + randomNum);
                    }
                    //IF OPTION IS NO
                    else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "GOODBYE");
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                }while(reply != JOptionPane.NO_OPTION);
                //END OF SECOND DO-WHILE


            }

        };
        //PART OF ANONYMOUS 
        ak.ask();       
    }


}

//Class Driver
package edu.pupr.LottoGame;

public class theLottoDriver {
    public static void main(String [] args) {

        theLotto lt = new theLotto(0);
        lt.start();

    }
}
```

Ouput should be something like this:
Enter Number: 3267

09/07/2019 09:50:23:

throw #1: 4392

throw #2: 8391

You lost !!!

Comment: `java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();`

Comment: This solved the beep sound, thank you.